# saving .wav files without showdialog in C#

Tags: c#, audio-recording, showdialog, wav

Problem: I don't want the user to decide which location the recorded WAV file should be saved,the wav file should save in `c:\` . for example when button 2 is clicked the wav file saves to `"c:\"`. I hope you guys can help me.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


//voice recorder

namespace recorder
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {   
      [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
      private static extern int mciSendString(string MciComando, string MciRetorno, int MciRetornoLeng, int CallBack);

      string musica = "";

      public Form1()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      }

      private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         label1.Visible = false;         //label1.Text=recording
      }


//starts recording what I say to mic

      private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)


      {
         label1.Visible = true;
         mciSendString("open new type waveaudio alias Som", null, 0, 0);
         mciSendString("record Som", null, 0, 0);
      }

//stops recording and shows a save form
//This is where the problem is.
/* I don't want the program to ask the user for location and file name and format to be    
saved as. I just want the file to save in c:\ with the filename "recording1" with format 
as .wav */

      private void btnStopnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {


         label1.Visible = false;
         mciSendString("pause Som", null, 0, 0);
         SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();
         save.Filter = "WAVE|*.wav";

         if (save.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) // this is where it needs to be altered
         {
            mciSendString("save Som " + save.FileName,null,0, 0);
            mciSendString("close Som", null, 0, 0);
         }
      }

//lets user to open a WAV file by browsing files

      private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {

         if (musica == "")                          
         {
            OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
            open.Filter = "Wave|*.wav";
            if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) { musica = open.FileName; }
         }
         mciSendString("play " + musica, null, 0, 0);
      } 
   }
}
```

Comment: Description : when I click button 2 the program asks from user to where to save the wave file. but instead I want it to save automatically to c:\ without asking the user to where to save.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't show the Dialog and put a constant string instead of using the instance of class SaveFileDialog.

```
var fileName = "C:/mySound.wav";
mciSendString("save Som " + fileName,null,0, 0);
mciSendString("close Som", null, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void StopRecordingAndSave(string OutputFolerPath, string OutputFileName)
{
   mciSendString(@"save recsound" + OutputFolderPath + OutputFileName + ".wav","",0,0);
   mciSendString(@"close recsound ","", 0,0);
}
```