# Can't save sound from microphone

Tags: c#, audio, save, microphone

I use the part of code below to enable the microphone to record and then i save it and play it with 2 buttons. But if in savedialog i save my .wav in desktop folder everything is fine and it create the test.wav(example) but if i will try to save it in any other directory/path it doesn't do anything.

I suppose that it can't create or save the sound. But i don't know why.

My code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


//voice recorder

namespace recorder
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {   
      [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
      private static extern int mciSendString(string MciComando, string MciRetorno, int MciRetornoLeng, int CallBack);

      string musica = "";

      public Form1()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      }

      private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         label1.Visible = false;         //label1.Text=recording
      }


//starts recording what I say to mic

      private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)


      {
         label1.Visible = true;
         mciSendString("open new type waveaudio alias Som", null, 0, 0);
         mciSendString("record Som", null, 0, 0);
      }

//stops recording and shows a save form
//This is where the problem is.
/* I don't want the program to ask the user for location and file name and format to be    
saved as. I just want the file to save in c:\ with the filename "recording1" with format 
as .wav */

      private void btnStopnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {


         label1.Visible = false;
         mciSendString("pause Som", null, 0, 0);
         SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();
         save.Filter = "WAVE|*.wav";

         if (save.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) // this is where it needs to be altered
         {
            mciSendString("save Som " + save.FileName,null,0, 0);
            mciSendString("close Som", null, 0, 0);
         }
      }

//lets user to open a WAV file by browsing files

      private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {

         if (musica == "")                          
         {
            OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
            open.Filter = "Wave|*.wav";
            if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
            {
                musica = open.FileName;
                mciSendString("play " + musica, null, 0, 0);
            }
         }

      } 
   }
}
```

I have found the code here : 
[saving .wav files without showdialog in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22418559/saving-wav-files-without-showdialog-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't open a file selection Box / SaveFileDialog.

Do this:

```
  private void btnStopnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     label1.Visible = false;
     mciSendString("pause Som", null, 0, 0);

     string filename = "whatever";
     mciSendString("save Som " + filename, null,0, 0);
     mciSendString("close Som", null, 0, 0);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, now it's create the .wav inside the debug folder of my project. How i could save it to a specific folder inside my debug folder? For example in folder MicMusic (it's folder that exists inside the debug folder)

Comment: Well you have to set the correct pathname in `filename`. Don't work with relative pathes, use an absolute path like `C:\temp\whatever.wav`